# Create Firefox Profile via Command Line

Tags: command-line, firefox, firefox-profile

Is it possible to create Firefox profiles via the command line? I need to programatically launch Firefox with different proxy settings. From my understanding, I can do this via creating a profile. However, I don't want to create these profiles manually.

Answer (score 16):

You sure can!

example:

```
firefox -CreateProfile john
```

check out the rest of Firefox's [command line arguments](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments).

Once your profile is created and configured you can launch the profile by doing the following:

```
firefox -P john
```

Comment: The `-CreateProfile` is not available in recent versions of Firefox anymore. Is there any manual way to simulate this command?

Comment: @AmirAliAkbari From a pseudo-answer by [jotomo](https://superuser.com/users/367072/jotomo) (who doesn't have enough rep to comment): "This still works in FF 31. If there is an instance of Firefox already running, the `-no-remote` option must be specified as well, otherwise the `-CreateProfile` argument is ignored and FF just opens another window."

Comment: To create a profile, you can also go to `about:profiles` and [do that](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-remove-switch-firefox-profiles).